# Generate uuid based on a namespace/string in Go

Tags: go, uuid

I would like to generate uuids based on a string value and also be able to check given a uuid, if it was generated using that string. I will use this in marking the uuids I use with my system's instance name. Is there a way to achieve that in Go?

Comment: Ideally uuid means a random string, this can not have any relation with any existing data. You can go for a workaround, generate uuid and append custom string in a fixed position. if you are afraid of string being sensitive information, you can again encrypt with base64

Comment: Base64 is not an encryption. It doesn't provide any security from prying eyes. About not being able to base UUIDs on data, see my answer below.

Comment: @TehSphinX, it will be very secure when it is just a 5 char substring in a 15 len string . out of which 10 is a uuid and only the developer knows where is the base64 starts and ends

Comment: Obscurity is not security.

Comment: @it'sme: [Kerckhoffs's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27s_principle)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are different types of UUIDs (See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Versions) although the list is not complete). Version 5 is the one that is generated based on user data.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/google/uuid"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(v5UUID("custom data"))
    fmt.Println(v5UUID("custom data"))
    fmt.Println(v5UUID("other data"))
}

func v5UUID(data string) uuid.UUID {
    return uuid.NewSHA1(uuid.NameSpaceURL, []byte(data))
}
```

[Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/02qU5_m6QP4)

UUID version 5 is based on a namespace UUID. In the example above `uuid.NameSpaceURL` is used. It is a well known namespace UUID. You can replace it with your own static UUID or `uuid.Nil`.

Given the same data is available at verification time, the same UUID can be generated again and compared.

Caveat: Since the same data will lead to the same UUID, the data must be unique or the UUID will not be unique. Different namespace UUIDs can be used for different domains where uniqueness is given.

---

Edit based on comment below:

None of the UUID formats that exist can accommodate for those requirements.

The only one that could is the new [Version 8](https://www.ietf.org/archive/id/draft-peabody-dispatch-new-uuid-format-04.html#name-uuid-version-8). That is a custom format for custom based implementations.

Downside: you are on your own. You have 122 bits you can set however you like. At the same time collisions are your own problem / risk.

The Go `uuid` library mentioned above can create a uuid from any 16 byte long []byte with `uuid.FromBytes`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, this way we bind a string to a UUID. In order to check if a UUID was generated by a particular instance, we need to keep track of all strings that we previously used to generate UUIDs, which is effectively the same as just storing all previously generated UUIDs.

As the questions asks, is there a way of generating unique UUIDs from the same string, and given a UUID check if it was generated using a particular string?

Comment: See my edit above to answer your question. About verifying if a UUID is generated based on a certain string, you might want to look into cryptographic signatures.